# Vertically center a title with fixed height in css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a header

```
<h1>My Header</h1>
```

It has a height of `150px` and a `font-size` of say `1.3em;`
How can I make the header text vertically centered with CSS.
I would rather not wrap it in a container DIV (wrapping divs really defeat the whole CSS idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to add this rule:

```
h1 {
    line-height: 150px;
}
```

You don't need to set the height value, and the font size doesn't affect the vertical align.

Comment: The font size does affect .. the font size though ;)

Comment: Won't this be a problem if the text ends up being multiple lines long?

Answer (score 3):

If the height of the title is 150px, could you also set the `line-height` to 150px?

```
h1
{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As alexmeia noted it seems the height is unncessary as the line-height already stretches the tag.